# Comparing mouse-overed element data to data in each element of the selection

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have circled svg elements which contain data specifying the region they represent. 
I want to be able to hover each circle element and have any of elements within the selection to be highlighted if they share the same region as the element being hovered over.

I have read this can be achieved by the following code but i am having trouble understanding how the value of the element being hovered over is being compared to the values of the other elements.

I am aware the on function adds an event listener to all the selected elements for the mouseover event but can't make sense of how this leads to obtaining the value of the element being hovered over and how that element gets access to both the data from the other elements and the data attached to itself for the comparison to happen in the if statement.

Could someone help me understand this, so i can begin to implement this kind of effect.

```
d3.select("svg").append("g").attr("id", "teamsG").attr("transform", "translate(50,300)")
.selectAll("g").data(incomingData).enter().append("g").attr("class", "overallG")
.attr("transform",(d,i) =>"translate("+(i * 50)+",9)") 


var teamG = d3.selectAll("g.overallG");

teamG.on("mouseover", highlightRegion);

function highlightRegion(d){
d3.selectAll("g.overallG").select("circle")
.attr("class", p => p.region == d.region ? "active" : "inactive")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the only important functions/methods here:

```
teamG.on("mouseover", highlightRegion);

function highlightRegion(d){
    d3.selectAll("g.overallG").select("circle")
        .attr("class", p => p.region == d.region ? "active" : "inactive")
}
```

Let's start with the `"mouseover"`. When you do this:

```
teamG.on("mouseover", highlightRegion);
```

The `highlightRegion` function gets passed 4 things:

- First argument: the element's datum;
- Second argument: the element's index;
- Third argument: the element's parent group;
- `this`: the element itself;

Therefore, the `d` here...

```
function highlightRegion(d){
```

... is the element's datum. Then, inside the `highlightRegion`, there is a `selection.attr` with a function as a callback:

```
.attr("class", p => p.region == d.region ? "active" : "inactive")
```

Exactly like what we had for `selection.on`, the callback for `selection.attr` gets passed 3 arguments and `this`. So, the `p` here is the datum for each element in the selection (which is `d3.selectAll("g.overallG").select("circle")`).

**Long story short**: we have the datum for the hovered element (`d`) and, in the `attr` callback, we compare it with the datum of each element in the selection (`p`), using the conditional operator:

```
p.region == d.region ? "active" : "inactive"
```

For each element in that selection if its datum property `region` is the same (but coercing, because `==`) of the datum property `region` of the hovered element it gets an `"active"` class, otherwise its class is `"inactive"`.

Finally, bear in mind that you can name the parameters the way you want. As the first argument is the datum, D3 developers normally name the first parameter as `d` (for datum). Then, in the inner callback, I'd personally name the first parameter as `e`, and then `f`, and so on... the person that wrote that code named it as `p` for whatever reason, but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: How does the ```selection.on``` only pass the datum of the element that triggers the even if the selection uses selectAll and therefore a selection of all the data ( an array) binded to the ```overallG``` g elements.

Comment: Well, those two things are not related.

Comment: I feel like i am missing something here, i am still confused

Comment: `selection.on` passes only the data of the hovered element. This is straightforward. Then, the `attr` in the selection (`d3.selectAll("g.overallG").select("circle")`) gets passed the data of all elements in the selection. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes thanks, i get it. selectAll just adds the on. and the on. only accesses the datum of the element with the triggered event. Its just not as straight forward as you put without the confirmation on how the two selections are working together to produce the desired effect.

Comment: @KvothesLute actually, no: there is nothing being added to anything. It's just an inner selection. That's why I said it's straightforward. Imagine two JS loops, one inside the other, looping over different iterables.